# How to access object properties with names with special characters? (like quotes)

Tags: excel, powershell

I have an issue with not being able to access object properties in PowerShell that have been loaded from an XLSX file using **PSExcel module**.

The object looks something like this:

[image]

The issue I have is that I cannot access the **"Title"** property.
I tried different approaches:

```
$row.'"Title"'
$row.'\"Title\"'
$row.'`"Title`"'
$row.`"Title"`
$row["\"Title\""]
$row["Title"]
```

None of these worked.

Anyone could help? Thank you!

Comment: Your image shows `$rows` but you're trying to access singular `$row`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure something else isn't going on with your object? Your first example listed worked for me. See screenshot of an object I made with an imported CSV below -

[image]

Comment: When I load the object and do ```foreach ($row in $rows) {$row}``` it prints out nicely. But once I do ```foreach($row in $rows) {$row.'"Title"'}``` with the parameter copied from the Get-Member command, there is no output...

Comment: What happens when you do something like `$row | select -ExpandProperty '"Title"'` ?